# Rotate 2D Object Towards Mouse & Stop After Full Revolution

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, rotation

Essentially what i'm trying to recreate is a dial with a min and max setting. The player clicks and drags the mouse around the dial to move its position but I would like for it to stop at a full rotation even if the mouse keeps revolving around the object.

The only way I've come up with this is to keep track of the distance covered by the drag.

So I use 360f - StartingAngle for the distance it is allowed to travel ( I know this doesn't account for negative direction however you want to think about it ).

I then calculate a previous angle and next angle and find the difference and then add that to the total.

Then I was checking if the total > 360f - starting angle for slerping my rotation.

Problem I'm running into is when it crosses the threshold between 359.9 degrees and 0 degrees of course the difference comes up with a negative number and I'm not sure if I'm going about this the best way cause I can't seem to come up with a way of determining whether they crossed that threshold or they just went back really far.

````
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Dial : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector2 direction;
    float speed = 20f;
    float startingAngle;
    float angle;
    float angleRotationTotal;
    float previousAngle;
    Quaternion rotation;

    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            direction = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
            angle = angle < 0f ? angle + 360f : angle;


            if (startingAngle == 0f)
            {
                startingAngle = angle;
                SetPreviousAngle(startingAngle);
            }

            SetAngleRotationTotal(angle);
            SetPreviousAngle(angle);


            if (angleRotationTotal > 360f - startingAngle)
            {
                rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(0f, Vector3.forward);
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else
            {
                rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Angle, Vector3.forward);
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Rotation, Speed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            angleRotationTotal = 0f;
            previousAngle = 0f;
            startingAngle = 0f;
        }
    }

    private void SetAngleRotationTotal(float currentAngle)
    {
        if (currentAngle - previousAngle > 0f)
        {
            angleRotationTotal += currentAngle - previousAngle;
        }
    }

    private void SetPreviousAngle(float currentAngle)
    {
        previousAngle = currentAngle < 0f ? currentAngle + 360f : currentAngle;
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Have you looked at using [Mathf.DeltaAngle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.DeltaAngle.html) to help deal with the 0/360 wrap-around issue?

Comment: I admittedly havent actually although that looks promising i'm gonna look into that right now.